# Plotting graphical analysis of chaotic behavior

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, physics

I am trying to plot some results of chaotic behavior in a system based on a paper for one of my classes.  I am a physics undergrad.  I found some sample code online springy.nb which I have been trying to manipulate to fit my situation.  Here is my code so far.  I think the problem is my non-understanding of getting the x to iterate.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

```
springalt[{c_, a_, x_}, {rs_, vs_}, 
  tmax_] := {ϕ[t], ω[t], Mod[θ[t], 2*π]} /. 
  NDSolve[{ϕ'[t] == ω[t], ω'[
       t] == -c (((
            Sqrt[(Cos[ϕ[t]] + a)^2 + (Sin[ϕ[t]])^2] - 3)/
            Sqrt[(Cos[ϕ[t]] + a)^2 + (Sin[ϕ[t]])^2])*a*
           Sin[ϕ[
             t]] + (((√((x0 - 
                    Cos[ϕ[t]])^2 + (0.6*Sin[(2*π)/3] - 
                    Sin[ϕ[t]])^2) - 
                3)/(√((x - 
                    Cos[ϕ[t]])^2 + (0.6*Sin[(2*π)/3] - 
                    Sin[ϕ[t]])^2)))*((0.6*Sin[(2*π)/3] - 
                 Sin[ϕ[t]])^2*Cos[ϕ[t]] - 
              x*Sin[ϕ[t]]))) - ω[t], θ'[t] == (
      2*π)/3, ϕ[0] == rs, ω[0] == vs}, {ϕ[
      t], ω[t], θ[t]}, {t, 0, 1 tmax}][[1]]
poincarealt[{c_, a_, x_}, ics_, tmax_] := 
 Block[{sol = springalt[{c, a, x}, ics, tmax]}, 
  Print[ParametricPlot3D[{sol[[1]] Cos[sol[[3]]], 
     sol[[1]] Sin[sol[[3]]], sol[[2]]}, {t, 0, tmax}]]; 
  Print[Plot[sol, {t, 0, tmax}]]; 
  Union[Select[
      Table[{t, sol}, {t, 0, tmax, .001}], #[[2, 3]] < 10^-2 &], 
     SameTest -> (Abs[First[#1] - First[#2]] < .1 &)] PlotStyle -> 
   PointSize[Medium]]
```

Comment: What are good values for the parameters? Probably all you need to do is call `poincarealt[{c_, a_, x_}, ics_, tmax_]` with appropriate values.

Comment: c=10, a=6 I know the attracting x0 is around 6.38

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected errors to get you started, but the physical equations themselves may not be accurate.

```
springalt[c_, a_, x_, rs_, vs_, tmax_] := NDSolve[{ϕ'[t] == ω[t], ω'[t] == 
    -c (((Sqrt[(Cos[ϕ[t]] + a)^2 + (Sin[ϕ[t]])^2] - 3)/
    Sqrt[(Cos[ϕ[t]] + a)^2 + (Sin[ϕ[t]])^2])*a*                     
    Sin[ϕ[t]] + (((\[Sqrt]((x - Cos[ϕ[t]])^2 + (0.6*Sin[(2*π)/3] - 
    Sin[ϕ[t]])^2) - 3)/(\[Sqrt]((x - 
    Cos[ϕ[t]])^2 + (0.6*Sin[(2*π)/3] - Sin[ϕ[t]])^2)))*((0.6*Sin[(2*π)/3] - 
    Sin[ϕ[t]])^2*Cos[ϕ[t]] - x*Sin[ϕ[t]]))) - ω[t], θ'[t] == (2*π)/3,
    ϕ[0] == rs, ω[0] == vs, θ[0] == 0}, {ϕ[t], ω[t], θ[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]

tmax = 10; sol = springalt[10, 6, 6.38, 1, 1, tmax];
Plot[Evaluate[{ϕ[t], ω[t], Mod[θ[t], 2*π]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}]
ParametricPlot3D[{ϕ[t] Cos[θ[t]], ϕ[t] Sin[θ[t]], ω[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

[image]

Note that no initial condition was provided for `θ[t]`, so I chose `θ[0] == 0`.  `Union[...]` probably is meant to be part of a `ListPlot` calling sequence to produce a return map, but insufficient information is provided to correct it.